# Why am I getting "_OBJC_CLASS_$..., referenced from:" linker error when I have correctly linked frameworks?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, linker, compiler-errors

**My Problem**

I getting "_OBJC_CLASS_$..., referenced from:" linker error when compiling some Xcode projects (it happens in both iOS and Mac projects) I have correctly linked frameworks and imports.

**Setup**

- One application target
- One test target
- All frameworks linked correctly

On compile I get the following linker errors:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_JGCountdownTimer", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in JGCountdownTimerTestCase.o

for many classes that are used in tests.

**What I've Tried**

- Checked that imports are all present
- Removed all non standard frameworks
- If I compile a class for both the test target and the app target it fixes the issue. But then I get other warnings from the compiler.

Comment: In your Target - Build Phase check if JGCountdownTimer.m file is missing ?

Comment: As I'm sure you know, this means that the name (JGCountdownTimer) was used during the compilation process, but during the linking, the object file wasn't found. Does JGCountdownTimer come from a binary or a class file? The only time I had an issue with this was due to circular referencing. Could that be the case? If it is, use the @class directive. Good luck.

Comment: Hey chaps - thanks for commenting. I fixed the issue before I posted, but I couldn't find any other posts with the answer I found, so I was putting up a question so I could answer it myself and have an authoritative answer!

Comment: And the solution was to add `GCC_SYMBOLS_PRIVATE_EXTERN = NO` to the build settings.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Quick Answer**

Copy and paste the following line into your build settings:

GCC_SYMBOLS_PRIVATE_EXTERN = NO

In the target build settings look for "Symbols Hidden by Default". For the Debug configuration you want "No".

I've had this problem on and off for many months and I've just discovered why.

Comment: You can also prefix your `@interface` with `__attribute__((visibility("default")))`

Comment: In build setting where to paste  that GCC thing?

Comment: Search for GCC_SYMBOLS_PRIVATE_EXTERN and then set it to No

Comment: When i search for GCC_SYMBOLS_PRIVATE_EXTERN I get Symbols Hidden by Default which is already set to No. Any other solution?

Comment: @Wevah Thanks so much for your comment! I would have loved if you posted your solution as an answer. I ending posting my experience with the technique in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61020812/213871)

Answer (score 15):

I faced a similar problem. I got the linker error:

`_OBJC_CLASS_$_MyClass`

The problem was that I had declared an `@interface` for `MyClass` but had not declared its corresponding `@implementation`.

The fix was to simply add

```
@implementation MyClass
@end
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this could be the problem, but with the new compiler, any obj-c that aren't explicitly referred to/invoked will not be linked from libraries. This causes problems when you implement categories in libraries for example.

Try adding '-ObjC' to 'additional linker flags' in the build settings panel for your target. *shrug*

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer - I was posting this because I actually found the solution and it drove me freaking CRAZY that I couldn't find the answer anywhere else so I thought I'd post it here for some other hapless soul who gets this linker error and can't understand why.

Comment: This answer is a bit misleading. When linking static libraries, by default the compiler (gcc and clang) will only link members of the library that are referenced somehow. Specifying the `-ObjC` linker flag means link all members that have Obj-C class/category information. This doesn't affect dylibs at all, or application code, just static libs.

Comment: kevin: true... it was a stab in the dark a bit :)

Answer (score 0):

## objc_class_$textfieldvalidator referenced from

Compile doesn't include those copied files in its compile list. To fix this error
select the file or folder, then go to the Build Phases panel and open the Compile Sources step, then click the + button and add them all file or folder.

Right click on a project folder, click "Add Files to ...", select the file(s), click the Options button and select the target, then click Add.