# Not sure how to export Objective-C classes. Undefined symbols for architecture i386

Tags: objective-c, linker, clang

I'm trying to do some work on GTK+ on OSX and I'm having a little trouble because, to be honest, I'm not all that familiar with Objective-C. I have enough programming experience that I quickly got up to speed on the basic syntax, and I can look up what I need in documentation. But the problems I'm having are related to linking the library and exposing the classes to the program I'm linking to.

GTK+ is a C library, but the OSX backend includes a couple Objective-C classes. They're not exposed as public API, they're only used internally; but for something I'm working on I'd like to try to expose these classes publicly.

For reference, here is one of the classes:

https://github.com/GNOME/gtk/blob/gtk-2-24/gdk/quartz/GdkQuartzWindow.h
  https://github.com/GNOME/gtk/blob/gtk-2-24/gdk/quartz/GdkQuartzWindow.c

I've changed the build system so that it installs the header files. I have another source file (outside the gtk+ build system) that does something like:

```
GdkQuartzWindow *win = [[GdkQuartzWindow alloc] /* other messages... */ ];
```

When I try to compile I get a linker error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  ".objc_class_name_GdkQuartzWindow", referenced from:
  pointer-to-literal-objc-class-name in main-a8d029.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I'm not very familiar with how Objective-C compiler/linker works and having trouble understanding how I can (or if I can) solve this.

When I run `nm libgdk-quartz-2.0.dylib  | grep GdkQuartzWindow` I see a lot of messages on this class:

```
00057120 t -[GdkQuartzWindow beginManualMove]
000575c0 t -[GdkQuartzWindow beginManualResize]
00056c50 t -[GdkQuartzWindow canBecomeKeyWindow]
... (many more) ...
000b2030 s .objc_class_name_GdkQuartzWindow
```

At the bottom of that list, you see the thing that the linker is complaining doesn't exist. But if I use `nm -g` instead of `nm` then nothing is shown, so something is not being exported correctly.

For normal C symbols, the build process builds an alias file that includes

[Apple's docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/CppRuntimeEnv/Articles/SymbolVisibility.html) give me the impression that this shouldn't be a problem when my target is i386 (which it currently is). They say:

> In a 32-bit OS X project, these visibility controls apply only to the C or C++ subset of your code. They do not apply to Objective-C classes and methods. Objective-C class and message names are bound by the Objective-C runtime, not by the linker, so the notion of visibility does not apply to them. There is no mechanism for hiding an Objective-C class or method defined in a dynamic library from the clients of that library.

But, I am receiving an error saying I have undefined symbols, so my error seems to contradict this. If I change this line so that it's allocating an `NSWindow` instead, everything works fine; so it's importing the AppKit stuff correctly. It just seems that I'm doing something wrong with trying to expose the classes and their methods.

Any chance someone can point me in the right direction?

Comment: To be clear, are you changing the way the dylib is built when you say that you've "changed the build system so that it installs the header files"?

Comment: No, I just added those header files to the list of header files that are installed with "make install".

Comment: Your own project's makefile, or GTKs, though?

Comment: gtk's.  It's installing the headers so my external project can find the headers and import them. But when the external project tries to link, it fails to find the symbols.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. That Apple doc hasn't been updated in almost 5 years.. are you using GCC to build either GTK or your own project? Clang may work differently. Or, it seems to me from reading the doc that if the dylib isn't being built for 32-bit OS X only, it will hide the symbols; and you're sure you are building the dylib for that configuration only? I tried to get this to build myself to check but it's too involved. One more thing - can you replace in your code the class name with `NSClassFromString(@"GdkQuartzWindow")` and see if you can at least run correctly?

Comment: Yeah, I'm sure I'm building for i386 right now. When I run `file libgdk-quartz-2.0.0.dylib` it prints out `libgdk-quartz-2.0.0.dylib: Mach-O dynamically linked shared library i386`.  I'll try the NSClassFromString thing and see what that gives me, thanks.

Comment: woot! That seems to have fixed it! It just compile and my test program ran, so I think I may now be officially unblocked! If you post this as an answer on here I'll be happy to mark it as the solution.

Comment: I discovered the official documentation you linked is wrong about symbol visibility in ObjectiveC. Really, same compilation flags, code attributes and concepts apply. See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61020812/213871)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a temporary workaround, you could replace references to the class symbol in your code with calls to `NSClassFromString` passing the class name as an argument. For example:

```
GdkQuartzWindow *win = [[NSClassFromString(@"GdkQuartzWindow") alloc] /* other messages... */ ];
```

This has long-term maintainability issues, though, as it depends on the name of the class remaining unchanged. I suspect that the Apple doc may be out of date or wrong for current compilers. Perhaps check to see if the value being substituted in gdk/quartz/Makefile.in for `$(GDK_HIDDEN_VISIBILITY_CFLAGS)` indeed is the empty string on your platform, and if not, changing that may be a more viable long term solution for your needs.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem in a library with mixed C/C++ code and an ObjectiveC wrapper. In this situation I was compiling the whole library with `-fvisibility=hidden` gcc/clang flag. This has an immediate effect of also hiding all ObjectiveC class symbols. A not so known/used technique is to also decorate classes with visibility attributes. This widely used for C/C++, but it will also work for ObjectiveC declared types. Let's first create a `OBJC_MYLIBRARY_API` macro that will enable visibility on compilation units in a `libdefs.h` file:

```
#pragma once

#if defined(OBJC_MYLIBRARY_SHARED) || !defined(OBJC_MYLIBRARY_STATIC)

#ifdef OBJC_MYLIBRARY_EXPORT
    #define OBJC_MYLIBRARY_API __attribute__ ((visibility ("default")))
#else
    #define OBJC_MYLIBRARY_IMPORT
    #define OBJC_MYLIBRARY_API
#endif

#else
    #define OBJC_MYLIBRARY_API
    #ifndef OBJC_MYLIBRARY_EXPORT
        #define OBJC_MYLIBRARY_IMPORT
    #endif
#endif
```

Then you declare an Objective C class with the public API macro in the header:

```
#pragma once

#import "cboclibdefs.h"

OBJC_MYLIBRARY_API
@interface MyClass : NSObject
- (id)init;
@end
```

Then in the implementation just ensure the symbols will be exported defining the OBJC_MYLIBRARY_MACRO:

```
#define OBJC_CODEBINDER_EXPORT
#import "MyClass.h"

@implementation MyClass

- (id)init
{
    return [super init];
}

@end
```

This way `MyClass` symbols will be available in the generated shared library.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest making sure you are using the `-ObjC` flag when linking to GTK+. You can add it under "Other linker flags" in your target Build Settings. If this does not work, you might try adding `-all_load` linker flag.

This will affect how the library is loaded and make sure all the symbols are recognised. This is actually useful when linking a library containing Objective C classes, since there are some optimisations that are done by the linker (i.e., when a static library defines a category but does not use it directly), but maybe it will help in your case as well.

[See this](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1490/_index.html) for an explanation.

Comment: It turns out I did not have those in the flags, but adding them didn't seem to make a difference. :(